# Thread stuck in readUTF()

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, datainputstream

I have the following class:

```
public class Prices {

    String priceValues;

    public String getPriceValues() {
        return priceValues;
    }

    public void setPriceValues(String priceValues) {
        this.priceValues = priceValues;
    } 
}
```

This is my `run` method in the `SocketServer` class:

```
public void run() {
      while(true) {
         try {
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());

            System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            prices.setPriceValues(in.readUTF());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to " + server.getLocalSocketAddress()
               + "\nGoodbye!");
            //server.close();

         }catch(SocketTimeoutException s) {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
            break;
         }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
         }
      }
   }
```

Everything runs fine but I want to store what I am receiving from the client in such a way in which it can be accessed by any class. So I created a class called `Prices`.

However, the thread gets stuck on the following line:

```
prices.setPriceValues(in.readUTF());
```

The `prices` variable is not null, and everything runs fine when I take this line out.

Comment: You should not recreate the `DataInputStream` every time around the loop. Create it before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println(in.readUTF());
prices.setPriceValues(in.readUTF());
```

You're calling `in.readUTF()` twice. It's most probably not what you want. Remove the first line, or store the result in a variable:

```
String s = in.readUTF();
System.out.println(s);
prices.setPriceValues(s);
```

Note that setting and getting a field from multiple threads without any synchronization is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(in.readUTF()); 
prices.setPriceValues(in.readUTF());
```

You must have to store the result in a variable, then you can print or do anything you want with this variable.